# Solr CSV Uploader PHP script consumes CPU

Tags: php, csv, solr, server

I am running Solr 6.0 on a dedicated server with a Core 2 Duo 2.66GHz CPU and 4GB of RAM.

I am using the below PHP script to upload multiple CSVs (a few dozen at once, each file averaging 40MB) from the browser to Solr. As I used top command to monitor server CPU usage while the CSV is being indexed, CPU usage is maxing out on its 2 cores. It sometimes makes the Solr server go down after a lot of CSV uploads.

Is this a script side problem that I should be fixing, and should I put some sort of sleep function somewhere in the code to ease the stress on the server?

Or is this a server spec issue, that I need a better server to do this kind of work?

```
<?php
// apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-curl


// curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?fieldnames=url,keywords,description,title&commit=true' -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8' --data-binary @$file
$fileoutput = 'solr-upload.txt';
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$timestamp =  time();
$servertime = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
$SOLR_SERVER = '127.0.0.1';
$CORE = 'core1';
ob_start();
$callback = &$_REQUEST['fd-callback'];
$url = 'http://'. $SOLR_SERVER .':8983/solr/'. $CORE .'/update/csv?fieldnames=id,keywords,description,title&commit=true';

if (!empty($_FILES['fd-file']) and is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fd-file']['tmp_name'])) {
    $name = $_FILES['fd-file']['name'];
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['fd-file']['tmp_name']);
} else {
    $name = urldecode(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']);
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
}

$header = array("Content-type:text/csv; charset=utf-8");
$post = $data;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); 
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($ch) {
    $outputstring = $name . ' success ' . $servertime . "\n";
    $output = 'Upload Success!';
    file_put_contents($fileoutput, $outputstring , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}else {
    $outputstring = $name . ' failed ' . $servertime . "\n";
    $output = 'Upload did not work!';
    file_put_contents($fileoutput, $outputstring , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

// $opt = &$_REQUEST['upload_option'];
// isset($opt) and $output .= "\nReceived upload_option with value $opt";
if ($callback) {
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $output = addcslashes($output, "\\\"\0..\x1F");
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><script type="text/javascript">',
       "try{window.top.$callback(\"$output\")}catch(e){}</script></body></html>";
} else {
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    echo $output;
}

?>
```

Comment: Try reducing the number of files submitted in parallel to be the same as the number of cores - you're probably already CPU/io limited at that time, and any further threads will just reduce performance (and require a lot more memory to handle). My guess is that you're getting Out of Memory-killed from the OS or the JVM.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will be trying out to reduce the files submitted in parallel to be same as number of cores. (in my case 2)